# Como referencio um context no EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estou desenvolvendo uma API em c# e uso o framework Entity e preciso criar uma migration.

Minha API precisa conectar com dois bancos de dados o banco interno e um banco externo, com isso , foi necessário a criação de dois `contexts`. O problema ocorre quando eu uso o comando

```
dotnet ef migration add migration_002
```

É retornado o seguinte erro:

> More than one DbContext was found. Specify which one to use. Use the '-Context' parameter for PowerShell commands and the '--context' parameter for dotnet commands.

Preciso selecionar um de vários *contexts* mas não consigo selecionar nenhum deles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque o -Context (--context se tiver usando o CLI dotnet) depois disso o caminho do context, algo tipo:

```
dotnet ef migrations <COMANDO> --context solução/models/NomeContext
```

Comment: obrigado @Rogerio Santos ajudou muito!!!

Answer (score 0):

Consegui criar a migration , ficou assim

```
dotnet ef migrations add migration_001 --context NomeDoContext
```